# Raspberry Pi : Obexpushd Error: cannot create file: File exists

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, obex

`ps auxw | grep obex-da
root      3119  0.0  0.1   4276  1880 pts/1    S+   13:07   0:00 grep obex-da
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# sudo obexpushd -B -n
obexpushd 0.11.2 Copyright (C) 2006-2010 Hendrik Sattler
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions.
Listening on bluetooth/[00:00:00:00:00:00]:9
Creating file "abc0.png"
Creating file "abc0.png"
Error: cannot create file: File exists`

If the file already exists,
Obexpushd returns an error.
Basically it is unable to overwrite the existing file.
Any solution?

Answer (score -1):

Try first deleting the file before you send the file, by sending `PUT` request **without body** or End-Of-Body header.
Then try sending the file again.